# SEO : dealing with duplicate url but same page

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting, seo

I'm running e commerce site in PHP. I've rewrite rules as,

```
RewriteRule ^[A-Za-z0-9-_]+/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/?$ product.php?seo_id=$1 [NC,L] #
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/?$ catalog.php?seo_id=$1 [NC,L] #
```

And some products would have duplicate links but i want them in google as one link which i preffer.

ex.

```
http://example.com/laptop/dell-1055
AND 
http://example.com/products/dell-1055
```

In my site I often using both URLs. Both URLs should be work, but i want to prefer the first URLs (`http://example.com/laptop/dell-1055`) and these URLs should be indexed in Google not the second URL.

How to achieve it. (I know it is achieved by canonical or 301 redirect but I've no idea how to implement it)

NOTE : Both URLs are processed in with a single page (eg. `product.php`)

Answer (score 2):

At the top of the HTML this file generates put a canonical URL `<link>` tag:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://example.com/laptop/dell-1055" />
```

Comment: Is it ok to put this code on the same page which is laptop/dell-1055?

Comment: Yes. You can have a canonical URL point to itself. It doesn't hurt anything.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have 301 rules that will redirect all old new URLs to the new ones with **permanent redirect** that will force search engines to only cache the pretty URLs:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+catalog\.php\?seo_id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ laptop/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+product\.php\?seo_id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ products/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^[\w-]+/([\w-]+)/?$ product.php?seo_id=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ catalog.php?seo_id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: What is bad in using canonical?  I want to have both links working but want 1st to be included in search engines.

Comment: Nothing bad but you will need to have **each and every** URL in canonical tag. So today it might be just `http://example.com/laptop/dell-1055` but imagine including all the laptops that your site will ever list under `/laptop/` in future. You will have to always keep adding those canonical URLs but this redirect rule is just once and for all done deal. And yes this also forces only pretty URLs to be indexed.

Comment: What if i would put php generated code in canonical tag.

Comment: You can do that but will be an inefficient way of doing things as PHP code will need to query some database also. So 2 extra slow steps after `mod_rewrite` ends: 1) PHP 2) DB query and remember if you have thousands of laptops what will be size of your page.

Comment: Hey but laptop/ is dynamic. I can't put it in .Htaccess. There might be different keywords instead. The page is fully dynamic.

Comment: If `laptop` is dynamic then what is your old `.php` URL that consists of `laptop`, as your question doesn't specify that.

Comment: I mean /lcd/, /books/, /desktops/ etc. But product comes after those keywords will be also reachable with /products/. All products will have independent unique ids.

Comment: Yes I understand that dynamic part didn't see any info on what your old `.php` URLs are for `/lcd/, /books/, /desktops/, /laptop/` etc

Comment: e.g. `/laptop/dell-1055` goes to `/product.php?seo_id=dell-1055` but it looses `/laptop/` in your internal URI so how is your `.php` code figuring out whether it is `/laptop/` or `/books/`?

Comment: No. There is not any practical use of that keyword. But for user url readability, I have put it into url. So it could also help in search engine rankings.